# Emacs imenu and speedbar+semantic fails because of indentation in c++ mode

Tags: c++, emacs, emacs-semantic, emacs-speedbar

My problem is that imenu or speedbar/semantic fails because of indentation. For this simple file, it is ok:

```
#include <iostream>
void bar() {
   std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
}
```

But if I want to put function bar in a namespace and indent its code:

- with speedbar (having `(require 'semantic/sb)` in init.el), I don't have the file tags in the speedbar frame, and I got "File mode specification error: (void-function c-subword-mode)" in minibuffer
- with M-X imenu, I got "No items suitable for an index found in this buffer" in minibuffer

Exemple code that fails:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    void bar() {
    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is not the namespace that makes it fail, but the identation. The following fails too:

```
#include <iostream>
    void bar() {
       std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
```

Any idea why and how to have it to work?

Thanks!!

EDIT: Ok the solution is indeed speedbar+sementics. It actually works (I had something wrong in my init.el...)

Comment: I would recommend you look at the promising `rtags` project @ https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags ; it has imenu functionality builtin: `rtags-imenu` / `C-x r I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, the example regexp from `imenu.el` is used together with `imenu-example--create-c-index`:

```lisp
(defvar imenu-example--function-name-regexp-c
  (concat
   "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ \t]?"        ; type specs; there can be no
   "\\([a-zA-Z0-9_*]+[ \t]+\\)?"    ; more than 3 tokens, right?
   "\\([a-zA-Z0-9_*]+[ \t]+\\)?"
   "\\([*&]+[ \t]*\\)?"         ; pointer
   "\\([a-zA-Z0-9_*]+\\)[ \t]*("    ; name
   ))
```

The caret `^` at the beginning means beginning of line. If you insert `[[:blank:]]*` behind it also function definitions with leading spaces are indexed.

I do not know whether stuff like

```
else if(...) {
...
}
```

gives false positives in this case. (You have to try.)

Actually, if I had sufficient time I would try to use `semantic` or `ctags` for the indexing. That would be much more robust.

Note, I did not try this. I just had a look at `imenu.el`. (Currently, I do not have much spare time. Sorry.)